# Validating REST Api response

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I have created a REST API using Spring Web MVC to expose data in a mongo collection. This API is supports both XML and Json formats. I generate the response using BasicBSONObject ( which is a linkedHashMap internally ) dynamically. So I don't keep track of the fields in my service code.

How could the consumers of this API validate the response from my services? If this was a SOAP based service I could have given a XSD for them. What am I missing here?

Comment: what prevents you from passing the overal XSD or JsonSchema as links (maybe within your header) in your response a client can use to download the schemas if needed and then validate the response body against the schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xsi:schemaLocation="http://path/to/your/xsd/file.xsd"` attribute in your response XML and host valid XSD on the URL.

It will be the duty of callers to validate the XML with the XSD.